# Analyze table in procedure

Tags: oracle-12c, plsql

I have many partitions to analyze and don't want to paste every single line to terminal so I'm trying to run a procedure for it, but I got complitaion error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE analyze_table
  BEGIN
    analyze table SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME partition (PARTITION) validate structure cascade into invalid_rows;
    analyze table SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME partition (PARTITION) validate structure cascade into invalid_rows;
    analyze table SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME partition (PARTITION) validate structure cascade into invalid_rows;
    END;
    /
```

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

```
SQL> SHOW ERRORS
Errors for PROCEDURE ANALYZE_TABLE:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/3      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of
         the following:
         ( ; is with default authid as cluster compress order using
         compiled wrapped external deterministic parallel_enable
         pipelined result_cache accessible rewrite
```

What is reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not place DDL commands directly in PL/SQL code. You can run them as dynamic SQL, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE analyze_table
  BEGIN
    execute immediate 'analyze table SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME partition (PARTITION) validate structure cascade into invalid_rows';
    execute immediate 'analyze table SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME partition (PARTITION) validate structure cascade into invalid_rows';
    execute immediate 'analyze table SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME partition (PARTITION) validate structure cascade into invalid_rows';
    END;
    /
```